# Why doesn't my YN-565EX fire with the RF-603II wireless triggers?

Tags: flash, wireless-triggers, yongnuo

I can't get the flash to fire with flash triggers on.  Can anyone help?

- Body: Nikon D7000
- Flash: Yongnuo YN-565EX
- Trigger: Yongnuo RF-603II wireless flash trigger

Comment: Please provide more information regarding what is attached to what and what settings are selected.

Comment: See http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/56682/why-does-the-yn-565ex-need-a-radio-trigger-with-the-yn-560-tx/56776#56776

Comment: And http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/56123/rf-flash-triggers-and-transmitters/56125#56125

Comment: Can you provide information on the settings used on the Camera, Flash and Triggers?